# Prove that $f(X \cap f^{-1} (Y)) = f(X) \cap Y$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $f(X \cap f^{-1} (Y)) = f(X) \cap Y$

Given that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty sets and that $f:X \to Y$ is a function. Let $X \subseteq A$ a non-empty subset of $A$, and $Y \subseteq B$ a non-empty subset of $B$.

Comment: I think you meant the function to be from $A$ to $B$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(a) \in f(X \cap f^{-1} (Y))$ where $a \in X \cap f^{-1}(Y)$. Then, $a \in X$ and $f(a) \in Y$. Thus, $f(a)$ is in the intersection and this shows the first inclusion.

Take $f(a) \in f(X) \cap Y$ where $a \in X$. Then, $f(a) \in Y$. So, $a \in f^{-1} (Y)$, and, $a \in X$. therefore, $a \in X \cap f^{-1} (Y)$ and so $f(a) \in f(X \cap f^{-1} (Y))$. This shows the other inclusion and the proof is done.